# graphQL with mongoDB - is it possible to be TOO flexible with a query?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, graphql-js

I've recently started learning and using graphQL and I see that a common pattern is to make queries flexible enough to accept inputs such as `_id`, `last`, `first`, `take`, etc.

Is this the right way to form queries or are there any design patterns or best practices that can be followed ?.

For example, here's a resolver for a collection that is searchable and limitable.

```
Query: {
clients: async (parent, args, context) => {
  return await mongoDb
    .getCollection(CLIENTS_COLLECTION)
    .aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          name: {
            $regex: args.input.text ? new RegExp(args.input.text) : '',
            $options: 'i'
          }
        }
      },
      { $limit: args.input.take || LIMIT }
    ])
    .toArray();
}
}
```

Should I also add inputs to find by `_id` in this same query? What about filtering and sorting? And is there such thing as too flexible?

Comment: This is quite subjective. In my opinion it really depends on your specific project and your specific needs. I would try to avoid doing too much work that is not obviously necessary, and keep in mind what's in the backlog just to not limit myself too much. Requirements can change many times during a project's life time. So make it as flexible as you think makes sense and change it when you need too. If you're not sure and need to choose, implement the option that's easiest to correct later.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [GraphQL-to-MongoDB, or how I learned to stop worrying and love generated query APIs](https://blog.solutotlv.com/graphql-to-mongodb-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-generated-query-apis/). It talks about a middleware package that leverages GraphQL's types to generate your GraphQL API and parses requests sent from clients into MongoDB queries. It features most of the standard query operations. This way you can enjoy all the flexibility offered by the package without having to implement it yourself for any change in your data models.

Disclaimer: this is my blog post.

The [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-to-mongodb) generates GraphQL input types for your schema field args, and wraps around the resolve function to parse them into MongoDB queries.

Given a simple, classic GraphQLType declaration:

```
const PersonType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'PersonType',
    fields: () => ({
        age: { type: GraphQLInt },
        name: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(new GraphQLObjectType({
                name: 'NameType',
                fields: () => ({
                    firstName: { type: GraphQLString },
                    lastName: { type: GraphQLString }
                })
            }))
        }
    })
});
```

For the most common use case, you'll build a field in the GraphQL schema with a `getMongoDbQueryResolver` and `getGraphQLQueryArgs`. The `filter`, `projection`, and `options` provided by the wrapper can be passed directly to the find function.

```
person: {
    type: new GraphQLList(PersonType),
    args: getGraphQLQueryArgs(PersonType),
    resolve: getMongoDbQueryResolver(PersonType,
        async (filter, projection, options, source, args, context) =>
            await mongoDb.getCollection('person')
                .find(filter, projection, options).toArray()
    )
}
```

An example of a query you could send to such a field:

```
{
    person (
        filter: {
            age: { GT: 18 },
            name: { 
                firstName: { EQ: "John" } 
            }
        },
        sort: { age: DESC },
        pagination: { limit: 50 }
    ) {
        name { 
            lastName
        }
        age
    }
}
```

There's also a wrapper and argument types generator for mutation fields.